# always create new file if file already exists with same location in C#

Tags: c#, file

I have created a new file using the code below. But if the file already exists then I need to create a new file with another file name. Is this possible?

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

bw.Write(b);
bw.Close();
fs.Dispose();
```

my file save location  is same.

Comment: Why not just check if it exists? `if(System.IO.File.Exists(filePath)) { /* change the filename here */ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use `File.Exists(filePath)` to checck if the fie already exists and choose another name in that case.

Comment: Race condition waiting to happen. You can use it as a performance optimization(if it's common for the file to exist), but `File.Exists` by itself isn't a good idea.

Comment: is it possible to delete the file at the time of some one is access the same file . because i got the error. it is used by another process using c#.net some code.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `FileMode.CreateNew` it will throw an exception if the file already exists.

> **CreateNew**
>   Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. This requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Write. If the file already exists, an IOException is thrown.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx

You can use it together with `File.Exists` to reduce the likelyhood of an exception, but just using `File.Exists` is problematic. A file can be created between your exists check, and opening it. If it's unlikely for the file to exist(for example you're using a randomly generated name), then skip the `File.Exists` check entirely.

Comment: To elaborate, using `FileMode.Create` instead of `FileMode.CreateNew` reduces the need to check if the file exists as it overwrites the file without throwing IOExceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, You can use:

```
 int i = 0;
 while (File.Exists(filename))
 {
   i++;
   filename = filename + i.ToString();
 }
 // save the File
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for.  However, just adding 'i' at every iteration would result in "filename0123456" instead of the anticipated "filename0", "filename1", etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
string FileName = "FileName"; // This var will be edited to FileName(1), FileName(2) and so on...
string BaseFileName = "FileName"; // To prevent cases like "FileName(12345)", we 'reset' it by having a "base name". 
int i = 1;

while (File.Exists($"{Directory}/{FileName}.txt")) 
{
    i = i + 1;
    FileName = $"{BaseFileName}({i})"; 
}
```

Something like this will do the trick, but I think overall this code can be optimised in some way, not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

As [CodesInChaos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5271000/212987) commented, we don't want to use File.Exist as status can change between lines.

```
int ind = 0;
while (true)
{
    var fileNamePart = $"MyFile_{ind}.txt";
    var fullPath = Path.Combine(@"C:\\temp", fileNamePart);
    try
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            byte[] info = new byte[0];
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
            return fullPath;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        // Expected when file already exists. Find next file name.
    } 
    ind += 1;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to distinguish between "file already exists" and other failures throwing an IO exception? I ask because I want to stop trying again in case of other failures and also prevent an infinite loop.